# Как склеить текстуры из модели человека, сделанной в Daz Studio в 1 файл

Tags: 3d

Я создаю модель персонажа в Daz Studio. После экспорта в Wavefront object у в директории с проектом появляется поддиректория Maps, в которой лежит куча картинок с текстурами глаз, торса, головы и других частей модели.

Как склеить все текстуры в один файл?
[image: текстуры]

Comment: А собственно зачем вы их хотите склеить?

Comment: @Kromster Я пишу программу на qml с 3D графикой. Вообще нет никакой документации, судя по примерам из Qt Creator можно загрузить текстуру из картинки, но только если она одна

Comment: @Kromster Есть уже рабочая моделька, но нужно вставить что нибудь серьезнее. Сам я так человека, к сожалению, не сделаю https://github.com/tripolskypetr/simpleqml3d Обратите внимание на IronMan.qml

Comment: Смотрите в сторону упаковки текстур в атлас (bin-packing), и вам придется объединить все UV координаты тоже.